# NuxtJS 2 meta tags SSR from API data

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I'm looking to set dynamic meta/title tags for my page based on data fetched from an API, so that my page links render nicely on discord, facebook etc. Currently I have the following:

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
head: {
    title: 'My App',
    htmlAttrs: {
        lang: 'en'
    },
    script: [...],
    meta: [...]
}
```

Then in my page itself, I was making my api call in the `fetch()` block, based on `this.$route.params.id` and using that data to override in my `head()` method, yet it doesn't seem to override the nuxt config defaults when pasting the link in Discord.

=== UPDATE ===

I have the following code:

```js
        head() {
            return {
                title: this.communityAsync.name,
                meta: [
                    {
                        hid: 'og-image', property: 'og:image',
                        content: `<myurl>?id=${this.communityAsync.id}`
                    },
                ]
            }
        },
        async asyncData({params}) {
            let resp = await axios.get(`<myurl>/${params.id}`, {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                }
            })
            let communityAsync = null;

            if(resp.status === 200) {
                communityAsync = resp.data
            }
            return {communityAsync: communityAsync}
        },
```

And when pasting the live link into discord, the embed still relies on the data set in the nuxt config js.

Answer (score 0):

Use `head(){}` instead of `head: {}`

The [`head` property](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-head#the-head-property) could be `Object` and `Function`, you can have dynamic meta/title tags via `Function`

```js
data() {
   return {
      blog: {}
   }
},
async fetch() {
   let { data } = await axios.get(`/blogs/${this.$route.params.id}`);
   this.blog = data;
},
head() {
    return {
        title: this.blog?.title
    }
}

// or using asyncData
async asyncData({ route }) {
    let { data } = await axios.get(`/blogs/${route.params.id}`);
    return {
        blog: data
    }
},
head() {
    return {
        title: this.blog.title
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the asyncData option, how are you returning data to blog?

Comment: @Flinty926 sorry for my carelessness, I‘ve updated it

Comment: Ah perfect, that makes more sense now, thank you. I'll give it a go and report back, thank you

Comment: Updated my initial post with more content, still not working via SSR

Comment: @Flinty926 make sure asyncData is only available in nuxt page component, but fetch is available in any components, or you may add a console.log() after axios get data

Comment: I think I figured it out, I believe it has something to do with <client-only> tags I have. I'm going to test it now

Comment: and was it related to <client-only> ? This issue is driving me crazy.